# How to run multiple services from .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, terminal, terminal-services

I would like to run selenium server from bat file. It means start hub and two nodes under the hub. On Ubuntu I have this script to do that:

```
  java -jar $jarFilePath -role hub & 
  java -jar $jarFilePath -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/ & 
  java -jar $jarFilePath -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/ & 
  exit 0
```

It is necessary to chain it with & cause the first command is still running and does not run next commands. But on Windows this does not work for some reasons. I found something like this for Win but still no success. It opens three terminal but nodes are not able to register to hub:

```
start cmd.exe /k "cd c:\Program Files\Selenium\Server & java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub"

start cmd.exe /k "cd c:\Program Files\Selenium\Server & java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.137.1:4444/grid/register/" 
start cmd.exe /k "cd c:\Program Files\Selenium\Server & java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.137.1:4444/grid/register/"
```

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: My assumption, `@CD /D "C:\Program Files\Selenium\Server"`, `start java.exe -role hub`, `<possibly some wait mechanism>`, `java.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.137.1:4444/grid/register/` etc.

Comment: What is this @CD /D ? Nodes are able to try to connect in 5seconds cycle. There is not needed to use wait.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `cd /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your commands are failing is because paths with spaces must be quoted (space is a token delimiter).

But the following will still fail because quotes cannot be nested, so the `&` is not quoted and the initial batch parser treats the line as two concatenated commands instead of a single `start` command.

For example, looking at the first line, this will not work

```
start cmd.exe /k "cd "c:\Program Files\Selenium\Server" & java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub"
```

To fix the above, many people would escape the `&`

```
start cmd.exe /k "cd "c:\Program Files\Selenium\Server" ^& java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub"
```

But I prefer to escape the outermost quotes so that I can write the commands as I would type them myself into the command prompt

```
start cmd.exe /k "cd ^"c:\Program Files\Selenium\Server" & java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub^"
```

Note that `cd` does not change your active drive by default. So say your active drive is `D:`, then the above will still not work. You would have to use either `cd /d "c:\Program Files\Selenium\Server"`, or else `pushd "c:\Program Files\Selenium\Server"`.

But it is probably simpler to `cd /d` or `pushd` before your `start` commands so that you only have to do it once. `START`ed processes inherit the environment of the parent.

There is no need for the sub-process to remain open after the service terminates, so better to use `cmd /c` instead of `cmd /k`.

Your full script could be

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\Program Files\Selenium\Server"
start cmd.exe /c "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub"
start cmd.exe /c "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.137.1:4444/grid/register/" 
start cmd.exe /c "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.137.1:4444/grid/register/" 
popd
```

But I'm not sure you actually need to explicitly run `java` within `cmd.exe`. You may be able to simply use the following

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\Program Files\Selenium\Server"
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.137.1:4444/grid/register/
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.137.1:4444/grid/register/
popd
```

Finally, you likely don't need a separate window for each process, in which case you can add the `/B` option to the `START` command. Put that immediately after `start`.

Comment: Some think that  [`"title"` is important](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) even if empty e.g. as `START ""  …`?

Comment: @JosefZ - Yes, I almost included a reference to that in my answer. The first argument to `start` is treated as a title if it is quoted. So if the command that you are `start`ing must be quoted, then you must precede the command arugment with a quoted title argument (empty quoted string is fine)

Comment: Also.. just semantics.. these aren't ***services*** as far as Windows is concerned.  Just processes.

Comment: Yes it works. Also does not need to use cmd.exe. Thanks a lot. God bless you!